# Deploying non-MVC website to IIS7 (Windows 2008) server from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2012, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

Is there a documentation or how-to on deploying non-MVC website from Visual Studio 2012?

I have seen some saying to use references (bin directory) which is all I need for Visual Studio 2012 but I haven't been able to get it to work.  Apperantly, there's a lot about it that I don't know about so is there friendly HOWTO documentation on it?

THanks...  Pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trials & errors, I learned a few things here.

To save yourself the troubles, use Nuget package manager and select the "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages 2" package and it takes care of the rest for you.

When you're done, your next steps is

A) Copy over "" scripts (razor stuff) that are found inside the ""'s of your web.config file to your production server's web.config.

B) Copy over the *.dll files that was installed from NuGet Manager.

That's it.  You're done!  The reasons for using the packages file is cuz it update your web.config file w/ filename and PublicKey you don't know of and put *.dll files into the BIN directory.  It takes care of it for you.  :-)

I don't know of a better way to do this.  At least I can use the razor and *.cshtml file without the MVC on the production environment.